# What type of volume is a Dockerfile VOLUME instruction creating?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Docker creates volumes using the newer `—-mount` parameter. Here, the key=value pairs specify the volume options. I am particularly interested in the parameter `type`.

- bind
- volume
- tmpfs

Which type gets created by Docker (and how can I specify this?) when I use

Dockerfile

```
VOLUME /etc/nginx
```

I would like to see `docker volume ls`
/etc/nginx

Then I can use another container with the `—-from-volume` to access it. What am I missing?

The documentation only states that a mountpoint must be specified when starting a container.

> The host directory is declared at container run-time: The host directory (the mountpoint) is, by its nature, host-dependent. This is to preserve image portability, since a given host directory can’t be guaranteed to be available on all hosts. For this reason, you can’t mount a host directory from within the Dockerfile. The VOLUME instruction does not support specifying a host-dir parameter. You must specify the mountpoint when you create or run the container.

This question could be rephrased as: How can I relate https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/ to a Dockerfile?

(I am completely aware of the benefits of having Docker daemon manager a volume rather than using a bind mount. This is my intention)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `VOLUME` instruction in the `Dockerfile` creates an anonymous volume that is bind-mounted in the container. For additional information ref. the [storage](https://docs.docker.com/storage/) doc: "Besides the name, named and anonymous volumes behave in the same ways". Example:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

VOLUME ["/src"]
RUN mkdir /src && \ 
    touch /src/file.txt
```

Build the image: `docker build --rm -t so:57703848 .` and run the container: `docker run --rm --name mycontainer -it --entrypoint cat -d so:57703848` (setting `cat` to keep the container running in the background just for example purposes).

Now you can use the `--volumes-from` to bind mount the volume from `mycontainer` into another container: `docker run --rm -it --volumes-from mycontainer ubuntu:18.04`
[image]

**Note**: "Anonymous volumes are not given an explicit name when they are first mounted into a container, so Docker gives them a random name that is guaranteed to be unique within a given Docker host." - a `docker volume ls` might turn up i.e.: `ccb199ae1396c2b9d49acc58559c739bd40b2ef37af50191fa3600ab6552fb20` (randomly generated). You can mount a named-volume to the anonymous volume in the `run` i.e.: `docker run --rm --name mycontainer -v myvolume:/src -it --entrypoint cat -d so:57703848`, the `--volumes-from` would work identical and the `docker volume ls` would output `myvolume`.

Comment: That‘s what I was looking for. I was about ready to start reading Go source code...

Comment: Glad I could help - edited with a note about naming the anonymous volume.

Comment: I wish the documentation for Docker were this precise. Docker has generally good documentation. (Dont wanna be too hard on them)

Comment: I would tend to agree, I was helluva confused at first with volumes in general. When I figured out that at the end of the day the “docker volumes” are nothing more than directories created in /var/lib/docker/volumes that are bind mounted as you would using the -v flag things really started to click.

Comment: By the way, you might want to move your VOLUME instruction to after the RUN. I think VOLUME is creating the path if it does not exist, the `mkdir` is trying to create it again.

Comment: No, if you remove the `mkdir` as-is (leaving just the `VOLUME` and `RUN touch /src/file.txt`) the `docker build` will bomb out during the `RUN` with `touch: cannot touch '/src/file.txt': No such file or directory`.

Comment: Well, I reversed the order of VOLUME and RUN (as-is). With my docker version (client 19.03.1-ce Arch Linux + daemon 1.13.1 API 1.26 on CentOS 7), I ran into errors complaining that the directory already exists (mkdir involved).

Comment: Interesting, possibly related to le me running with experimental features enabled and using buildkit (19.03.1 build 74b1e89 on Ubuntu 18.04). Thanks for the tip.